# How to convert a selenium webelement to string variable in python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchAttributeException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?locationId=sg%3A0&f_TP=1%2C2&orig=FCTD&trk=jobs_jserp_posted_one_week')
jobtitlebutton = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-title-link')
print(jobtitlebutton)
```

The output is a selenium webelement in the form of a list. I want to convert it into a string variable so that the list can contain all the jobtitles in text format. 
If I can get assistance in this it will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need list of links or list of jobs (e.g. "Datacenter Technician", "Test Manager")?

Answer (score 8):

In case, if you need a list of links to each job:

```
job_list = []
jobtitlebuttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-title-link')
for job in jobtitlebuttons:
    job_list.append(job.get_attribute('href'))
```

In case, if you want just a job titles list:

```
job_list = []
jobtitlebuttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-title-text')
for job in jobtitlebuttons:
    job_list.append(job.text)
```

Comment: Thanks alot it did helped me alot.

Comment: I also would want to know how I can click each of the job title and extract the job description for which the class name is 'content'.

Comment: I guess you should loop through `job_list` of links and do something like `description = "/n".join([i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]//ul/li')])`

Comment: Thanks alot. It surely helps