# Deriving text from Javascript webpage using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am trying to extract the text "This station managed by the Delta Flow Projects Office", from this website: https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ca/nwis/uv?site_no=381504121404001. This line is located under the div class `stationContainer`. Since this is a dynamic webpage, I'm using selenium to derive the html.

This is the html from the website.

[image: img]

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ca/nwis/uv?site_no=381504121404001"
browser.get(url) #navigate to the page
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='stationContainer']")

print (elem)
```

I get the this result from my print message:

> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="96fc124c0e2d1fd4cd86f61db272d52a", element="0.5862443940581294-1")

I'm hoping to derive the text by searching through the div class, but it seems I'm not going about this the right way.

Comment: You could get page source and then use a parsing library like bs4 or lxml

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000, when I get the page source, it doesn't identify this line of text since it's rendered from JS

Comment: Use selenium's get page source with a wait so that the javascript can render it

Comment: And check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011816/how-to-convert-a-selenium-webelement-to-string-variable-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the content you want to scrap is not actually dynamic. You can use [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to fetch the *`div class stationContainer`* content. What makes this a bit challenging is that the element you're searching is not between certain tags. So a solution to this is an easy string manipulation to extract the content between the `</form>` and the `<br/><br/>` tag, like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

soup = BeautifulSoup(get('https://your_url_here').text, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"stationContainer"}):
    print str(i).split('</form>')[1].split('<br/><br/>')[0].strip()
```

This code produces the appropriate result!

Answer (score 1):

`elem` is a list not a `string`. Try this:

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='stationContainer']")[0]
print elem.text
```

That prints out all the content. So you probably need a better selector or a way to parse the rest of it out.

Answer (score 1):

`print (elem.text)`

`elem` is a WebElement object, hence the printed message. If you want to access the text, you need to add `.text` to the end, or if you want to grab some other attribute you can do something like `elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')`.

Also, since the div element has a lot of other text, you're going to be getting a lot more text than what you want. I haven't looked into other similar pages, but perhaps you could extract what's between `</form>` and `<br><br>` in the div's html.